# Negative Dogecoin Balances?

Tags: dogecoin, bitcoin-core-accounts

Through dogecoin-cli, I sent half the dogecoins I own to an external address. Now, when I call the listaccounts function, I get this:

```
[root@web ~]# ./dogecoin-cli listaccounts
{
    "" : -25001.00000000,
    "doge" : 48136.85072100
}
```

Notice how the "" has -25001.00000000. I am using a query from php to get the balance of "doge" and display it to users. That returns 48136.85072100, which is a problem, because I only have 23135.85072100 doge. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem general to all Bitcoin-derivatives. Perhaps you should edit your question to make it more general.

Comment: If you have multiple accounts: use `sendfrom` to send from a specific account. If you don't care about the accounts, use `getbalance`

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

> *rricci2009 commented:*
>
> After few transaction by `sendtoaddress` command, balance in "" became negative. I solved with the "move" command from another account to "". [...]

#### Cause

> *sipa commented:*
>
> That is expected behavior, if your incoming transactions credit accounts other than "", but outgoing transactions debit account "" (the default if you're not using `sendfrom`), the "" account will go negative. [...]

#### Mitigation

> *Tectract commented:*
>
> [...] So, is there a way to do something like a `sendtoaddress` command that won't leave me with odd negative balances?
>
> *gavinandresen commented:*
>
> Use the `sendfrom` RPC command.
>
> And you can use the `move` RPC command to reset account balances to what you expect (and listaccounts to see all accounts / balances)

[Source.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2191)